# turtlebot_simulator (no kinect data)

Tags: gazebo, simulation, kinect, turtlebot, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when I run turtlebot simulation, there is no simulated Kinect. I'm sure that before some time it was working.

I'm using this command to run simulation:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

List of topics which are advertised:

```
/clock
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/paused
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/imu/data
/joint_states
/odom
/robot_pose_ekf/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/turtlebot_node/sensor_state
```

During start-up there is just this info (from pointcloud_throttle, kinect_laser and kinect_laser_narrow nodes):

```
waitForService: Service [/openni_manager/load_nodelet] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

Thanks for any advice...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28290/turtlebot_simulator-(no-kinect-data)/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2012-02-23**:
+1 I was just working on posting this question myself.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-02-23**:
what version of turtlebot, turtlebot_simulator, and turtlebot_apps do you have installed?

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2012-02-23**:
I have the latest installed from the repositories on ROS Electric on Ubuntu 11.10.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2012-02-23**:
I have also installed latest from deb repos on ROS Electric and Ubuntu 11.04.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-03-14**:
I pulled the latest from the package manager and everything is working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the gazebo.urdf.xacro file. The camera frame names were not correct and therefore the gazebo plugins couldn't initialize properly. It's fixed in 330:4253a4e5f257 . It's released in turtlebot 0.9.2

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0